# multiple polygon in loop in google map for new google.maps.Polygon not working under loop

Tags: angular

here is my code

this.overlays= [
this.ZoneData.forEach(e => {
this.positionArray =JSON.parse(e.zone_cities).map(e => ({lat: e.lat, lng: e.lng}))

```
   new google.maps.Polygon({
        paths:[...this.positionArray
        ], strokeOpacity: 0.2, strokeWeight: 1, fillColor: e.delevery_zone_colour_code, fillOpacity: 0.35
      })
    }),]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  new google.maps.Polygon({paths: this.positionArray ,strokeOpacity: 0.5, strokeWeight: 1,fillColor: this.zoneColor, fillOpacity: 0.35
  }),
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.